# Is this doable, a multi-purpose home server using either Linux Mint or Ubuntu Server with some additional software?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, linux-mint, nas, kodi

Ok, first of all I think this site would be the best fit for this question and that, it does not fit under serverfault though it is a server related question.

I thought of building my multi-purpose home server using linux mint or ubuntu server plus some addon software like xbmc and virtualbox.

The following server task are my priorities:

1. File (NAS), Media and Streaming Server
2. Media Center, using XBMC
3. Router and Firewall with Parental Control Features
4. Local Web Server with Virtual Host Support
5. Torrent/Seed Box
6. VPN Server
7. Git

...and with the following features:

1. Supports fake RAID
2. Supports Hardware RAID Controllers, Adaptec/HighPoint/Areca/3Ware.

UPDATE:

If it's doable in one single physical machine, then I'll start doing my research on how to build this project.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why this is question is voted down?

Comment: I presume since you're asking for nothing unusual, the question arises why you think it wouldn't work, or if your research told you something different, etc. Terdon's answer sums it up quite well. We mostly require questions to be based on actual and specific problems you're facing. Note that we don't delete questions just like this, especially if there have been answers people spent time writing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using any Linux, including Mint or Ubuntu. All you need to do is install the relevant software.

What makes you think it wouldn't work? Linux is primarily a server OS and the user-friendly Linuxes like Mint and Ubuntu are no different. Since you don't have any strange requirements, I see no reason why you would have any problems.

Comment: I've updated the question, is it doable in a single physical machine with all those server tasks I've mentioned above?

Comment: @GaryDapogi yes, of  course, why not? The only problem will be if you are trying to offer all these services to many many users in parallel. Even so, your limit will not be the software but the hardware. If your server can cope with the load it should have no problem with any of your requirements. If you are talking about thousands of users that's a different case and you should ask at server fault.

Comment: `What makes you think it wouldn't work?` I thought of incompatibilities and conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Using a server as a router, on the same box as where you run other services, necessitates you take security precautions lest things you don't intend be Internet-accessible.

Be prepared to spend some serious time studying `iptables` so that you can secure your router and implement NAT.  You'll also need to become familiar with the internals of Linux networking to use `OpenVPN` or any VPN software correctly.

I have read here and there that there is some weirdness with 3ware RAID controllers under Linux.

Also, playing media on the same box that you are doing routing and VPN serving will require some horsepower so don't skimp on the specs.  Especially if you also intend to transcode or convert video on the same box.

Comment: Of course, I'll provide the resources for this project generously. I may strike out the Router task and delegate it to my dd-wrt based router hardware. I really intend to transcode video files and add some DLNA feature using XBMC. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Samba and XBMC
2. [Link to instructions for xbmc](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Installing_XBMC_for_Linux)
3. Router built-in
      firewall iptables 
      Parenteral control = I am not sure about this one
4. Local web server  = apache
5. Check package manager a number of choices exist.
6. VPN server   this feature exists, if it is not in the package manager (it should be) you can compile something from source.
7. Git = of course it is supported
8. Software RAID = The kernel, the core of all linux distros, has this built-in
9. Hardware RAID = see #8  I am using hardware raid with the Adaptec 5805 right now.